# What is this keyboard's country?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Can someone tell me what layout is used in this fujitsu keyboard? When I bought it I was told it was british, but comparing it with UK layout it does not match (I'm Italian, Iwas asked to buy a UK layout and once seen this, it was rejected, but as it didn't costed me much I decided to keep it).

[image: keyboard]

Comment: It is definitely not UK, which has `"` on `Shift-2` and `£` on `Shift-3`. It's probably US, but I have only UK keyboards, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a US ISO (also sometimes called "English International") keyboard. The placement of the two <kbd>\</kbd> keys is the ISO layout used by standard UK keyboards, but the keycaps are labeled with US characters.

Comment: The two back-slash keys are not standard on UK keyboards. The right-hand key, next to `Return` is normally `#`/`~`.

Comment: @AFH: Neither is `@` above `2`. Nonetheless the positioning is used by the UK keyboard, with different keycaps.